# Magneto Store takes too much time to load due to server responses late

Tags: magento2, database

I am using `Magento 2.4.3` and `php -v: 7.3.3`.

When tring to load magento frontend or admin this page takes to much time to load. Also, when checked in network tab i found that it `local.gccgamer.com` site which is taking 1.2 minutes to wait for server response which is too much. As you can see in the image below.

[image]

I don't know how to resolve this issue and make the page loading speed normal. So, please let me know what is the actual reason that makes my website to take more time to load.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Magento 2.4.3 runs on PHP 7.4

Please see - https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html

Are you using the recommended Varnish Cache?

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cache/varnish/config-varnish.html

1.2 min is not acceptable in any ways. Please check your cache is enabled.